# Exporting data through variable to another screen

Tags: react-native

Thank you in advance for all your help.

Iam trying to build a part of application that would pass the user to their profile page on successful login and load their profile information based on ID variable that would be received from the backend. I can't get my head around of how to do it as if I try to export tempId it gives me an error, same goes with navigation.navigate...

I would really appreciate a nod towards the right direction here.

```
import React, {Component, useState} from 'react';
import {
            StyleSheet,
            Text,
            View,
            KeyboardAvoidingView,
            TextInput,
            TouchableOpacity,
            AsyncStorage,
            Alert
            } from 'react-native';
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import api from '../services/api';
import axios from 'axios';



export default function Form ({}) {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');


        async function handleLogin(){
                const response = await axios({
                method: 'post', 
                url: 'http://apiboardgeek.co.uk/users/login',
                data: {email: email, password: password }
            });
        //console.log('HELLO')
        console.log(response.data)
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('accessToken', response.data.accessToken);
        const tempToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('accessToken');
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('id', response.data.id);
        const tempId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('id');


        if(response.data.message=="User Logged in succesfully"){
            //alert('Login succesful');
            //navigation.navigate('Profile')
            Actions.UserProfile();
        }
        // else{
        // alert('Login failed, please try again');
        // return null;
        //  }

        //navigation.navigate('UserProfile');
        }

        return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior = "padding" enabled>
            <View>
                <TextInput style={styles.inputBox} 
                underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)' 
                placeholder="Email"
                placeholderTextColor = "#000000"
                selectionColor="#fcd9d9"
                keyboardType="email-address"
                value={email}
                onChangeText={setEmail}
                onSubmitEditing={() => this.password.focus}
                />
                <TextInput style={styles.inputBox} 
                underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)' 
                placeholder="Password"
                secureTextEntry={true}
                placeholderTextColor = "#000000"
                selectionColor="#fcd9d9"
                value={password}
                onChangeText={setPassword}
                ref={(input) => this.password = input}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.button} onPress={handleLogin}>
                    <Text style = {styles.buttonText}>Sign In</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({


    container : {
        flexGrow: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },

    inputBox :{
        width: 300,
        backgroundColor: '#dedcdc',
        borderRadius: 25,
        paddingHorizontal: 16,
        fontSize: 16,
        marginVertical: 10,
        paddingVertical: 12

    },

    button : {
        width: 300,
        backgroundColor: '#a19f9f',
        borderRadius: 25,
        marginVertical: 10,
        paddingVertical: 16,

    },

    buttonText : {
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: '500',
        color: '#ffffff',
        textAlign: 'center',
    }


});
```

Thank you all in advance and apologies if some of the information is missing. At this stage the head is about to explode and I can't think straight...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using AsyncStorage in another screen to access data helped.

to access "tempId" I used the line from above:

```
        const tempId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('id');
```

just in the screen from which I needed to access it.